# STM32F072RB does not receive/send data over SPI in slave mode

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f0

I am using the 
[STM32F072RB](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l072rb.html)
uC to receive and transmit data over `SPI2` in slave mode with the following configuration:

```
CR1 = 0x0078
CR2 = 0x0700
AFRH = 0x55353500
MODER = 0xa2a0556a
```

The register `APB1ENR` is also properly configured.

The current program just checks the `RXNE` flag, reads the received data from `DR` and sends a random value writing to `DR`.

The status register when I receive data has the following value:

```
SR = 0x1403
```

The master sends data properly and I checked the signals at the slave pins (clock phase and polarity are identical on both sides and the NSS signal is cleared before sending SCK and data over MOSI).

I even configured the pins as inputs and I know I could read any digital signal the master could send.
With the current configuration it seems the slave receives something because the `RXNE` is set when the master sends data but the read value is always 0x00.

I have tried different configurations (software/hardware NSS, different data sizes, etc.) but I always get 0x00.
Moreover, the random value I send after reading `DR` is not sent to the outputs.

This is my current function, which is called continuously:

```
unsigned char spi_rx_slave(unsigned char spiPort, unsigned char *receiveBuffer)
{
    uint8_t temp;
    static unsigned long sr;
    if (!spi_isOpen(spiPort))
    {
        sendDebug("%s() Error: spiPort not in use!\r\n",__func__);
        return false;
    }
    if (spiDescriptor[spiPort]->powerdown == true)
    {
        sendDebug("%s() Error: spiPort in powerdown!\r\n",__func__);
        return false;
    }
    /* wait till spi is not busy anymore */
    while((spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->SR) & SPI_SR_BSY)
    {
        sendDebug("SPI is busy(1)\r\n");
        vTaskDelay(2);
    }
    sendDebug("CR1 = 0x%04x, ", spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->CR1);
    sendDebug("CR2 = 0x%04x, ", spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->CR2);
    sendDebug("AFRH address = 0x%08x, AFRH value = %08x, ", (unsigned long*)(GPIOB_BASE+0x24), *(unsigned long*)(GPIOB_BASE+0x24));
    sendDebug("MODER address = 0x%08x, MODER value = %08x\r\n", (unsigned long*)(GPIOB_BASE), *(unsigned long*)(GPIOB_BASE));
    sr = spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->SR;
    while(sr & SPI_SR_RXNE)
    {
        /* get RX byte */
        temp = *(uint8_t *)&(spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->DR);
        spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->DR = 0x53;
        sendDebug("-------->DR address = 0x%08x, data received: 0x%02x\r\n", &spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->DR, temp);
        sendDebug("SR = 0x%04x\r\n", sr);
        vTaskDelay(1);
        sr = spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->SR;
    }
    while((spiDescriptor[spiPort]->spiBase->SR) & SPI_SR_BSY)
    {
        sendDebug("SPI is busy(2)\r\n");
        vTaskDelay(2);
    }
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there anything I did not configure properly?

*Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Javier*

### Edit:

I switched to software NSS and copied the register values from a STM32CubeMX example I found online. I cannot use those libraries for this project but I would like to have the same behaviour.

The new values are:

```
CR1 = 0x0278
```

which means

- fPCLK/256 (the proper one for the communication speed),
- SPI enabled and
- SSM = 1 (software NSS).

```
CR2 = 0x1700
```

which means

- 8-bit data and
- `RXNE` event is generated if the FIFO level is greater than or equal to 1/4 (8-bit).

```
AFRH = 0x55303500
MODER = 0xa8a1556a
```

which means

- MISO, MOSI and SCK alternate function 5 (SPI2)
- NSS is not configured because now it is in software mode (slave is always selected).

I am still getting the same results and the eval kit with those libraries works fine using `SPI1` instead.
Therefore there must be another issue that has nothing to do with the register values.

Might there be any clock issue e.g. the pins need to get some clock?

*Thanks!*

Comment: _"CR1 =0x0078, CR2 = 0x0700, AFRH = 0x55353500, MODER = 0xa2a0556a"_ Firstly make your question and configuration human readable. Respect our time.

Comment: Does your master generate the clock. If not you will not send anything. You need to cast DR to byte if you want to send byte.

Comment: Yes, the master generates the clock properly and receiving that clock makes the SPI activate the RXNE flag.

Comment: I thought having the register values would be useful for anyone who might be willing to help. Should I just explain what every bit from every register means? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question to supply some of the information that others found missing. There is no mcu called *STM32072RB*, but only *STM32F072RB** and *STM32L072RB* (with "F" or with "L", resp.). Using only information given in the question and answer, I first thought both controllers could have been meant. However, only on the **F0**, the `SPI_CR2` register takes more than 8 bits, and the `SPI_SR` provides more than 9 bits, so the **STM32F072RB** must have been meant. => Edited the headline and tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The question points to a couple of mistakes which may explain why no receive has been observed:

1. GPIO configuration points to some wrong Alternate Functions / Modes:
   The question didn't state it precisely, but I assume that

   > ```
   > AFRH = 0x55303500
   > MODER = 0xa8a1556a
   > ```

   refers to GPIOB (otherwise, it wouldn't make sense with SPI2).
   This corresponds to the following pin configuration (see the
   [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936-stm32f0x1stm32f0x2stm32f0x8-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf),
   sec. 8.4.1, 8.4.10 and the
   [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f072rb.pdf),
   Table 16):

   ```
   PB15 - Alternate Function - AF5 = [INVALID]
   PB14 - Alternate Function - AF5 = [I2C2_SDA]
   PB13 - Alternate Function - AF3 = [TSC_G6_IO3]
   PB12 - GP Input (reset state)
   PB11 - Alternate Function - AF3 = [TIM_CH4]
   PB10 - Alternate Function - AF5 = [SPI2_SCK / I2S2_CK]
   PB09 - GP Input (reset state)
   PB08 - GP Output
   PB07 - Alternate Function - (unknown which, see register AFRL)
   PB06 - GP Output
   PB05 - Alternate Function - (unknown which, see register AFRL)
   PB04 - GP Output
   PB03 - GP Output
   PB02 - Alternate Function - (unknown which, see register AFRL)
   PB01 - Alternate Function - (unknown which, see register AFRL)
   PB00 - Alternate Function - (unknown which, see register AFRL)
   ```

   This is obviously not what the software is required to do.

   Solution: Make sure to configure **PB15=>AF0**, **PB14=>AF0**, either **PB13=>AF0** or **PB10=>AF0**, depending on your hardware.

   In order to avoid mistakes in doing so, you should follow the hint of @P__J__ and use speaking macros for constants assigned to MODER, AFRH etc.
   Using the HAL library provided by ST is a truly controversial subject among SO users, *but* one should really consider to use at least a header like `stm32f072xb.h` with macros like `GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL15`.
   If one represents all configuration register values as (bitwise) ORs of such macros, it is easier to re-check configuration against datasheets, and the famous
   [rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)
   will directly know what an unhappy developer is talking about.
2. Other clock activations might be missing:
   The question confirms that

   > The register `APB1ENR` is also properly configured.

   This is correct (as long as bit 14 is set).

   Additionally, GPIOB must be powered, i. e., bit 18 of `RCC_AHBENR` must be set.
   See again the 
   [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936-stm32f0x1stm32f0x2stm32f0x8-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf),
   sec. 6.4.8 and 6.4.6.
3. GPIO pins may be in wrong mode during debugging:

   > I even configured the pins as inputs and I know I could read any digital signal the master could send. With the current configuration it seems the slave receives something because the RXNE is set when the master sends data but the read value is always 0x00.

   Please note that for every GPIO pin, a unique mode is selected through the `MODER` register. If this is set to "Input" (`0b00`), the Alternate Function is disconnected and won't work with external signals.